How does one control chitta during japa/sadhana?
I understand it takes time to control the mind as a beginner. But does it mean I have to force back my thoughts onto the deity I'm focusing on everytime my mind wanders? Have you controlled your chitta?

Vairagya + Abhyaasa are really the only two factors in this. It does take years, you have to be willing to keep at it. Put in the time, and get Vairagya by reading Raama Gita or Avadhuta Gita, every few days, among many other similar texts. There's 20+ Gitas, which are fairly easily available, all of whom are a gem for this purpose.
Additionally, for controlling the mind, Tarpanaa is an extremely underutilized and effective tool.
Try to meditate in Sandhyaa Kaala as well, if possible (before sunrise and just after sunset). The Praana Sandhyaa is also ideal, when both your nostrils are expelling an equal amount of air. Maintain a state of Sandhyaa in the body as well, by not doing too much or too little of anything. The same goes for the mind.
Additionally, you should pray to any Devataa you have any connection to, and also to Ishvara, via the means of Pranava, to quickly let the mind fall under control.
It took me 3+ years to reach Sabija Samadhi, while meditating 1+ hour everyday on average, along with other practices. Expect at-least that long, if not more.
The key part is Vairagya from other things and attachment to the Ishta. Even if you meditate 10 hours per day, if you don't have Vairagya towards your finances, or your relationships or food or playing games and so on, that 10 hours is almost entirely useless, you'll reach a roadblock at one point or another that you won't improve from.
Think of it like a multiplicatory effect. Abhyaasa * Vairaagya. If Vairagya is 0, then your result is 0, and the same is true the other way around.
You do have to force back your mind to the Deva, but it should almost be automatic once you have enough attachment. Til then, I'll recommend just making sure you pray or do Naama Japa whenever possible, whenever it comes to your mind or whenever you feel like it. The connection and Bhakti won't increase by following 50 rules, it didn't for me, anyways. Treat the Ishta like your best friend who is forgiving and wants to support you, instead of your boss that you need to report good things to or he'll get angry.
After a certain level of connection is established, you'll start to feel the presence of the Ishta, and that point only is it ideal to start meditating on him, as far as my understanding reaches.
